# Delete statement are working but doesn't delete rows

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to make a delete statement on which I want to delete some articles that are in another selected table.
I created the statement but when I run it, it doesn't delete something. It's running but no rows deleted.

```
delete from article  where (client_id, art_no) in ( select art_no, client_id from art_del as A 
inner join (select distinct client_id from article) as D on a.cliend_id = d.client_id 
where label not in (0,-1));
```

The data in the where clause looks good, but when I execute with the delete it won't delete something.

Comment: If you run the select stand-alone, does it return anything?

Comment: Yes, it returns what i want.. @jarlh

Comment: It returns  multiple art_no and client_id

Comment: If you do  `select from article  where (client_id, art_no) in...` you get some results?

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa , it returns 0 rows

Comment: What if you change your `WHERE` clause to be `WHERE label not in (0,-1) AND label IS NOT NULL`?  Teradata used to have some funky behavior with `NOT IN` and `NULL` values in previous releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The where clause is this:

```
where (client_id, art_no)
```

so the pair has 1st `client_id`  and then `art_no`
but in the subquery the order is differenet:

```
select art_no, client_id
```

Change to:

```
delete from article  
where (client_id, art_no) in ( 
  select client_id, art_no
  from art_del as A inner join (
    select distinct client_id 
    from article
  ) as D on a.cliend_id = d.client_id 
  where label not in (0,-1)
);
```

Comment: I changed, and in where/select are the same column order, where(art_no,client_id), select art_no,client_cd ... and still have the same problem

Comment: The code you posted in your question is wrong. If you still can't get the results that you want this means that either the logic of your code is wrong or your actual data are different than you think. In any case nobody can guess what the problem is.